# Shuffling images with buttons matching the shuffle

Tags: java, android

I am trying to layout 10 image buttons numbered 1-10 randomly on screen. 
I used an **array list and Collections**. Shuffle command to shuffle the background `drawables`.
But I cant seem to tie the button listeners to these random images.

```
// assigned arrays here
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
Button[] buttonimages = new Button[10];
List<Button> list;
// Global Variables
int[] buttonarray =     {R.drawable.button1,R.drawable.button2,R.drawable.button3,R.drawable.button4,R.drawable.button5,R.drawable.button6,R.drawable.button7,R.drawable.button8,R.drawable.button9,R.drawable.button10};
int idarray[] = {R.id.number1,R.id.number2,R.id.number3,R.id.number4,R.id.number5,R.id.number6,R.id.number7,R.id.number8,R.id.number9,R.id.number10};
```

// then I add to arraylist and shuffle

```
public void randomnumbers2() {

    for (int z=0;z<10;z++) {
        buttons[z] = (Button)findViewById(idarray[z]);
    }
    for (int k=0;k<10;k++) {
        buttonimages[k] = (Button)findViewById(buttonarray[k]);
    }
    list = new ArrayList<Button>(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) list.add(buttons[i]);
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (int z=0;z<10;z++) {
        buttons[z] = (Button)findViewById(idarray[z]);
    }

    for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(idarray[j]);
        ((Button) list.set(j, buttons[j])).setBackgroundResource(buttonarray[j]);
    }
}
```

But my buttons are defined like this:
setup  buttons

```
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number7);
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number8);
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number9);
    button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number10);
```

Problem is, 
when I click the first button. It has an image of number 5, in the 1st position, but its still associated with button #1. Basically I have 2 rows of 5 numbers mixed up. I want the button click to respond to button 5, not button1.

Comment: please finish up describing your problem.

Comment: sorry guys, not sure what happened there. to finish describing:

Comment: it has an image of number 5, in the 1st position, but its still associated with button #1. basically i have 2 rows of 5 numbers mixed up. I want the button click to respond to button 5, not button1. hope that makes sense. thx

Comment: You do have xml file for layout? I guess u do as you are referring to `R.id......`. 
If you want to move your buttons around, static layout is the problem. You need to do it dynamically from code (positioning buttons).

Comment: yes, I am using xml file for initial layout.  how would I go about moving buttons around randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started,

```
LinearLayout ll;
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // create a layout
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        buttons.add(createButton(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(buttons);

    for (Button b : buttons) {
        ll.addView(b);
    }

    setContentView(ll);

}

private Button createButton(final int i) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(i + "");
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Clicking button: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    return b;
}
```

Here, I am just trying to create buttons and set index as the display text. You can set your background resources to pictures or whatever you would like to. Hope this helps.

---

To have 2 rows of 5 buttons, you will need three linear layouts. Here we go for the code...

```
 LinearLayout ll;
    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create main layout which will host two linear layouts vertically
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //create another two linear layouts which will host 5 buttons horizontally
        Linear linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        Linear linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buttons.add(createButton(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(buttons);

        //add first 5 buttons to first layout
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            linearLayout1.addView(buttons.get(i));
        }
        //add remaining 5 to second layout
        for (int i=5;i<10;i++){
            linearLayout2.addView(buttons.get(i));
        }
    //add two layouts to main layout
      ll.addView(linearLayout1);
      ll.addView(linearLayout2);


    //set main linear layout to be main layout of the actvitiy.
        setContentView(ll);

    }

    private Button createButton(final int i) {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(i + "");
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Clicking button: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is what I was looking for, Ill give it a shot and post response.

Comment: seems like this may work, but the final view is just showing one of my buttons filling entire screen, either its just showing the last button of the arraylist, or Im missing something with the layout view. sorry I'm just used to layouts with xml, kind of weak with dynamic layouts. thanks

Comment: the view I want, is 2 rows with 5 buttons horizontally in each row.